# What does it mean when someone says "your brain must be full"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Today I had a discussion with my colleague and I was telling her that I am thinking of these 1-2-3 items to do for a long while but couldn't do because of my bad time management. She replied that "your brain must be full".

Could you someone please explain what does it mean when someone says "your brain must be full" in above context?

Answer (score 1):

It's a joke. She means that you have too much on your mind.

Comment: Thank you, I will leave the answer un-accepted for now for other answers.